# Custom back-propogation

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am experimenting with Tensorflow, and have the following problem

I want to use the iteration

`w_{t} := w_{t} - ag_{t-1}`

where `t` is the time, `a` is the learning rate, and `g(0)` is pre-specified. Since the gradient is not a trainable weight, I am not able to simply initialize it. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I fully understand your question. Why not initialize your gradient (I call it G here) to a zero tensor of the same shape as w_t? Then if you want to implement SGD, you can accumulate the gradient of each sample from a random batch on G and finally update your w_t.